# How to unit test a function that contains a lambda function that uses Predicate

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I've been trying to unit test this function for days, but can't seem to work it out, and I have similar functions in all the services which really lowers the code coverage. Is there a way to unit test it, if not maybe just make jacoco/sonarqube ignore it?

```
public Specification<ContratEntity> getSpecification(ContratDto dto) {
        List<DepartementEntity> departementEntities = securityService.checkDepartementFiltre();
        String[] filtreBus = securityService.checkBuFiltre();
        List<TypeContratEnum> typeContratEnums = securityService.checkTypeContratFiltre();
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            if (dto.getNumero() != null && !"".equals(dto.getNumero())) {
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("numero")), "%" + dto.getNumero().toLowerCase() + "%"));
            }
            if (dto.getBu() != null && !"".equals(dto.getBu())) {
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("bu")), "%" + dto.getBu().toLowerCase() + "%"));
            }

            if (dto.getDepartement() != null && dto.getDepartement().getAbreviation() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("departement").get("abreviation")), dto.getDepartement().getAbreviation().toLowerCase()));
            }

            if (departementEntities != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.or(
                        root.get("departement").in(departementEntities),
                        root.get("departement").isNull()
                        ));
            }
            if (filtreBus != null) {
                predicates.add(root.get("bu").in(filtreBus));
            }

            if (typeContratEnums != null) {
                predicates.add(root.get("type").in(typeContratEnums));
            }

            if (dto.getLbvFournisseur() != null  && dto.getLbvFournisseur().getCnuf_frn() != null && !dto.getLbvFournisseur().getCnuf_frn().equals("")) {
                predicates.add(cb.or(
                        cb.like(cb.lower(root.join("lbvFournisseur", JoinType.LEFT).get("cnuf_frn")), dto.getLbvFournisseur().getCnuf_frn().toLowerCase()),
                        cb.like(cb.lower(root.join("hlvFournisseur", JoinType.LEFT).get("cnuf_frn")), dto.getLbvFournisseur().getCnuf_frn().toLowerCase()),
                        cb.like(cb.lower(root.join("mlvFournisseur", JoinType.LEFT).get("cnuf_frn")), dto.getLbvFournisseur().getCnuf_frn().toLowerCase())
                ));
            }
            if (dto.getLbvFournisseur() != null && dto.getLbvFournisseur().getRaison_sociale() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.or(
                        cb.like(cb.lower(root.join("lbvFournisseur", JoinType.LEFT).get("raison_sociale")), "%"+ dto.getLbvFournisseur().getRaison_sociale().toLowerCase() + "%"),
                        cb.like(cb.lower(root.join("hlvFournisseur", JoinType.LEFT).get("raison_sociale")), "%"+ dto.getLbvFournisseur().getRaison_sociale().toLowerCase() + "%"),
                        cb.like(cb.lower(root.join("mlvFournisseur", JoinType.LEFT).get("raison_sociale")), "%"+ dto.getLbvFournisseur().getRaison_sociale().toLowerCase() + "%")
                ));
            }
            if (dto.getLbvFournisseur() != null && dto.getLbvFournisseur().getIce() != null && dto.getLbvFournisseur().getIce() != "") {
                predicates.add(cb.or(
                        cb.like(cb.lower(root.join("lbvFournisseur", JoinType.LEFT).get("ice")), dto.getLbvFournisseur().getIce().toLowerCase()),
                        cb.like(cb.lower(root.join("hlvFournisseur", JoinType.LEFT).get("ice")), dto.getLbvFournisseur().getIce().toLowerCase()),
                        cb.like(cb.lower(root.join("mlvFournisseur", JoinType.LEFT).get("ice")), dto.getLbvFournisseur().getIce().toLowerCase())
                ));
            }
            if (dto.getType() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), dto.getType()));
            }
            Predicate[] predicatesArray = new Predicate[predicates.size()];
            query.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("id")));
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(predicatesArray));
        };
    }
```

[You can find the coverage here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQltb.png)

Comment: I think you copy-pasted the wrong text. The first and last paragraph are identical. Can you [edit] with the intended text?

Comment: Integration tests could help with testing these methods

Comment: @knittl the thing is the function is never called directly in the controller, it calls a function that pass it as a parameter to the repository.findAll(), and when i tried to test the function it only test the part outside of the lambda function

Comment: @knittl I added an image that shows the jacoco coverage

Comment: Write integretation tests against a real, an in-memory db or a test container db. (or manually evaluate your predicate somehow)

Answer (score 0):

I would extract a method with Lambda expression contents, and then convert lambda itself to class field.
That way you will be able to test extracted method and lambda itself will not be included in coverage.
I would also make the field static to avoid unnecessary instantiation of functional interface implementation.